# Is there a running time limitation?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, imagemagick, dos, montage

I am running the DOS batch file below. My OS is Windows 7 with 3 GB ram. In Windows Explorer, I double-click the batch file and it runs fine with standard size images and combines the images into a larger image.  When I do everything exactly the same except with larger .jpg image files that are 1 MB, the code runs but produces a zero-byte file.  Could the batch file be timing out?  Do you think this is a limitation with DOS or ImageMagick?

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET MONTAGE="C:\Program Files\ImageMagick\Montage"
...
%MONTAGE% *.jpg -geometry +0+0 -tile 4x1 rows56-59-cols-32261-32400combined.jpg
```

Comment: there is no time lim8t on batch files, but if you want to know what happens, why don't you just run the command manually? then you'll see any error output.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!   I received the error message: "Maximum supported image dimension is 65500 pixels"
Is there another way to stitch these large images together?

Comment: You will not find any tool to create a JPG image with more than 65535x65535 pixels as [JPEG/JFIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) format does not support larger images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ImageMagick itself can support exa-pixel images on a 64-bit OS, see the specification [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/architecture.php#tera-pixel). Unfortunately, JPEG cannot support images over around 64,000 pixels on either side.

One solution might be to use a different outout format which does support larger images and ImageMagick will just quietly convert to that format for you. For example, `PNG` format uses 4 bytes for the width and height, so it should support up to around 4,000,000,000 pixels on either side. So you would do

```
montage *.jpg ... output.png
```

**Note:**

A `PNG` image may compress better or worse than the corresponding `JPEG` file depending on whether it is a computer-generated graphics type of image (good for `PNG`) or a conventional photograph type of image as shot by a camera (good for `JPEG`). But it you want the bigger images, you may be stuck with `PNG` anyway. There is also a `Large TIFF` format that you could investigate.

Comment: After more research I realized that I need to go a different route. I need to using mapping software to serve these tiles, keeping the tiles separate and hosting them with map server software.  Thank you all for your excellent advice, I really appreciate it.